# Bytearray vs Intarray

Tags: java

Please help to understand my java basics

I understand that bytes primitive can store values from -127 to 127  = So only Ascii values can be stored in byte primitive or Byte Array.
We generally store image,music and audio files in byte primitive or Byte Array as these files contains values between -127 to 127.
Cannot store Unicode values in byte array as these values can be upto 65536 -

1. Why we generally prefer to store bytes read from files in to bytearray?..why not into int array?
2. I have Chinese characters in a word document.
   I using inputstream (as opposed to reader class) to read the doc file and make a copy of it. Inputstream is read in to byte array and from there it is written to output file. 
   Chinese characters have more value than 128, so how those are stored in byte array? I had thought we should use only reader class(not INPUTSTREAM) to read word documents that has UNICODE characters.

   ```
   final String file="E:\\Users\\17496382.WUDIP\\Desktop\\chin.doc";
   final String file1="E:\\Users\\17496382.WUDIP\\Desktop\\chin1.doc";

   InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file); 
   OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file1);
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

   int bytesRead;
   while((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer))!=-1) {
       out.write(buffer);
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buffer));
   }
   ```

Comment: Really not hard to find this one with a web search: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description

Answer (score 1):

1. Because files are always bytes. They may be also other things (such as characters in a variety of encodings), but they're always bytes.
2. Encodings are used to transform a character into one or more bytes, allowing for more than 255 characters in a charset.

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Sorry, still not clear....Point1 - Both Int and Byte stores numbers. So why cant we store the read data in Int array instead of byte array?  When we read the inputstream.read(), its return type is int only..so why cant be it stored in int array..

Comment: Because if we store the data into an `int[]` either you'll be using 300% more memory than necessary, or you're requiring that the data is a multiple of 4. The reason that `read()` returns an `int` is because it will return `0-255` for all byte values, and `-1` for `EOF`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Point 2 - All Unicode characters(65536) can be stored in Int array right (as it supports to store value up to 2,147,483,647?. Why inputstream with int array for UNICODE is not supported and we use READER class to read character streams...

Comment: Point 3 - In the above code, I use chinese charaters whose byte value is 45897. When inputstream reads and write it to byte array, how byte array accepts 45897 value (when it cannot store more than 127)

Comment: `InputStream` is for bytes, not characters. `Reader` is the class for character reading. Also read the damn link, it explains everything.

Comment: sorry, link is missing. I do read that,Reader class is for characters. At the bottom, characters are also bytes correct?  I am able to read the Chinese characters, store it in byte array and read it from there...I am just trying to understand how UNICODE characters are being stored in byte array

Comment: The link is in my answer. Read it over and over and over until you understand. Don't ask me for any more clarifications. Everything's in the link.

Comment: sorry no more clarification. Cant see the link in your answer.can u pls send to my mail  dglsen@yahoo.com

Comment: Are you blind? [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)